ValueError: Namespace Atspi not available
I'm trying to use pyatspi.
I installed pygobject with conda install conda-forge::pygobject.
Then I ran both sudo apt-get install python3-at-spi and  sudo apt-get -y install python3-pyatspi, just in case.
I'm using a conda environment, so I added a symlink to pyatspy into the environment.
When I import pyatspi, it throws this error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "...", line 1, in <module>
    import pyatspi
  File "...", line 18, in <module>
    gi.require_version('Atspi', '2.0')
  File "...", line 122, in require_version
    raise ValueError('Namespace %s not available' % namespace)
ValueError: Namespace Atspi not available


Turns out I needed to provide GI_TYPELIB_PATH. This solved it:
export GI_TYPELIB_PATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/girepository-1.0

